# Xamarin iOS 6 SDK Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Well, I'm new in the `Xamarin` `iOS` developing and I think I started with the wrong foot.
I have `Xcode 5.0` and `Xamarin 4.0.14`. I'm looking to make my application work on `iOS 6` and `iOS 7` as my only testing device is an iPhone 3GS.
My problem is right now everything seems to point as I'm developing for `iOS 7`, all the buttons are borderless and as far as my knowledge goes, that it `iOS 7`.
So, how can I make my application work on `iOS 6` but still be approved by the Apple Store? (I've read that they'll soon stop accepting `iOS 6` app).

P.s I've already read [Xamarin.iOS Target iOS 6 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146688/xamarin-ios-target-ios-6-sdk)
but I'm still not quite there. I've started downloading Xcode 4.6.3 just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same problem. Uninstall Xcode, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin Studio and install these versions:

Download and install:

- Xcode 4.6.3

  - Go to [developer.apple.com/xcode/](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/). Log in. Click `View downloads` and on the second screen you should see `Xcode 4.6.3`
- Xamarin.iOS 6.4.3.0

  - In order to download this version log in to [xamarin.com/](http://xamarin.com/). Click on your account and then `Install`. Under the big green button click on `View all versions`. Here you can select `Xamarin.iOS 6.4.3 version`.
- XamarinStudio 4.0.12

  - The process is the same as for `Xamarin.iOS`. Only select the third column where you can find other version for `XamarinStudio`.

If you don't have the latest `Xcode` and `Xamarin.iOS` you won't be able to debug your applications with `iOS 7` on `iOS Simulator`.

**EDIT**

As [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012624/peter) pointed out, Apple will stop accepting apps which are not built with XCode 5 since February 2014.

Comment: Perfect answer, but will Apple still accept my Apps as they are made for iOS6? Won't they stop accepting them?

Comment: They will still accept them. We launched our latest app to AppStore this month and it got through revision without problems. We used the same versions which are in my answer.

Comment: Apple stop accepting apps built with older that Xcode5 on 1st Feb 2014. Hope you got your app submitted in time....

Answer (score 0):

You could download Xcode 4.6.3 from the Apple developer portal to developer for iOS 6.  Or, you could follow the information at [Is it possible to install iOS 6 SDK on Xcode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423896/is-it-possible-to-install-ios-6-sdk-on-xcode-5)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point you to [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538491/targetting-ios-7-but-supporting-ios-5-monotouch/19539086#19539086) and add a couple remarks on top.

That said by adjusting your deployment target to version 6.0 you could start developing. The fact that you only have access to an IPhone 3GS has both advantages and disadvantages.

On the plus side you can be pretty sure that your app will be running screaming fast on all recent iOS hardware, if performance is acceptable on such an ancient device as the 3GS.

The major disadvantage of your setup is that youl would have to rely solely on the simulator to ensure iOS7 compatibility. It's a gamble. And you will have to rely on the AppStore reviewers to know the outcome. (Hint: I've been there)