# Xamarin Studio - suddenly stopped working

Tags: ios, xamarin

Today i've restarted my mac and suddenly Xamarin is not working anymore. I've tried to run a simple project with just a Console.WriteLine("test") and when i'm trying to run it on a simulator ( with the debugger attached ) I'm not getting any error but the app is not starting ( it only shows a black screen like he's waiting for something ). If i'm trying to run it without the debugger attached, i'm getting this error in the console:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.RegisterMap (Int32 size, MTClassMap* map) [0x00051] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Class.cs:44 at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.Initialize (MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.InitializationOptions& options) [0x00012] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Class.cs:31 at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.Initialize (MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.InitializationOptions& options) [0x00053] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:102 2013-12-01 18:31:37.884 MetroMap[981:80b] Unhandled managed exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (System.NullReferenceException) at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.RegisterMap (Int32 size, MTClassMap* map) [0x00051] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Class.cs:44 at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.Initialize (MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.InitializationOptions& options) [0x00012] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Class.cs:31 at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.Initialize (MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.InitializationOptions& options) [0x00053] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:102 mono-rt: Stacktrace:

mono-rt: Native stacktrace:

mono-rt: 0 MetroMap 0x000b4d5d mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 349

mono-rt: 1 MetroMap 0x000bfd2a sigabrt_signal_handler + 122

mono-rt: 2 libsystem_platform.dylib 0x05408deb _sigtramp + 43

mono-rt: 3 ??? 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295

mono-rt: 4 libsystem_sim_c.dylib 0x05125e12 abort + 127

mono-rt: 5 MetroMap 0x00232023 monotouch_unhandled_exception_handler + 291

mono-rt: 6 MetroMap 0x000b558b mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 91

mono-rt: 7 MetroMap 0x000b45a9 mono_handle_exception_internal + 3817

mono-rt: 8 MetroMap 0x000b36b9 mono_handle_exception + 41

mono-rt: 9 MetroMap 0x0005a084 altstack_handle_and_restore + 148

mono-rt: 10 ??? 0x0f7da7e4 0x0 + 259893220

mono-rt: 11 ??? 0x0f7da744 0x0 + 259893060

mono-rt: 12 ??? 0x0f7d89e0 0x0 + 259885536

mono-rt: 13 ??? 0x0f7d8acf 0x0 + 259885775

mono-rt: 14 MetroMap 0x000e4686 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 790

mono-rt: 15 MetroMap 0x0017ea9f mono_runtime_invoke + 127

mono-rt: 16 MetroMap 0x00222d80 monotouch_init + 1312

mono-rt: 17 MetroMap 0x0021bc22 main + 1970

mono-rt: 18 MetroMap 0x000032d5 start + 53

mono-rt:
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

used by your application.
```

Also it does not work on the device.

I've tried to clear Xamarin cache ( users/myuser/library/xamarin and xamarin studio ). Also i've tries to clear the simulator.

If i'm trying to make in xCode a sample project everything is working fine on so the problem is surely in Xamarin. I've tried to switch channels in stable/beta/alpha and i have the same problem...

Any ideas?

Comment: What versions of XCode, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin Studio are you using?

Comment: XCode 5.0.2 ( 5A3005 ) and the latest Xamarin Stable version ( 4.3.0 )

Comment: Follow these steps to reinstall Xamarin http://stackoverflow.com/a/19587180/1441667 . Choose the versions of XCode, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin Studio which you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue here.
Same project works on my laptop, but not on my desktop computer.
Trying re-installing Xamarin

Comment: Hello there.  Can you help me do that? I've tried removing Xamarin Studio.app from Applications and also clearing the cache and then reinstalling but it's the same.

Comment: Is there any information how to reinstall xamarin from scratch?

Comment: I deleted everything in the xamarin folder and all frameworks from developer folder. Then re-installed xamarin